# nativescript angular tabview fails to display on iOS

Tags: angularjs, nativescript, tabview

I have a simple angular nativescript application. The initial (only) page contains a simple tabview with two tabs. Each tab contains a single label.

When the app launches the tabs are shown, but the label on the initial tab isn't displayed. When I tab to the second tab, its label displays, when I tab back to the first, its label now displays.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-tabview",
  template: `
  <TabView #tabview>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab1'}">
        <Label text="This is Label in Tab 1x"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab2'}">
        <Label text="This is Label in Tab 2x"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
  </TabView>
`,
})

export class TabViewComponent {
}
```

I'd appreciate any feedback on what I'm missing.

Thanks
Colin

**Fixed**

Although the display shows both tabs, and the tab text colors indicate that the first tab has been selected, when I look at the selectedIndex property in ngAfterViewInit the value is undefined.

If I set it to zero in ngAfterViewInit, then the initial tab's contents are shown.

Is this a bug? Should I initially select a tab programmatically like this or is there an html attribute that I could use?

Thanks

Colin

Answer (score 1):

I think this is normal behavior for NativeScript Angular projects, while using `TabView`. In regard to that you could setup `selectedIndex` TabView property from the html. You could review the code below.

```
<TabView selectedIndex="0">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab1'}">
        <Label text="This is Label in Tab 1x"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab2'}" >
        <Label text="This is Label in Tab 2x"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
 </TabView>
```

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, I'll try that.